# How to choose Kangaroo algorithm parameters?

Tags: encryption, algorithm-design, discrete-logarithm

I am implementing pollard kangaroo to compute the discrete logarithm of a group element $G$ of generator $g$. $G$ is a$\mod p$ multiplicative group ($p$ a prime number). So, I want to solve $g^a=h$ knowing $a\in[[0,w]]$.

What I am basically doing:

1. Define $w=2^{58}$
2. I define $k$.
3. Split $G$ into $k$ subset $S_i$.
4. I define $f(x)=xg^{2 ^ {x \mod k}}$
5. From here I make two kangaroo walk alternatively...

The first wild kangaroo : $y_0=h$ and $y_{i+1}=f(y_i)$. I store the values in a Hash map.
The second tame kangaroo : $x_0=int(w/2)$ and $x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$. I store the values in another Hash map.

Whenever a kangaroo value at an iteration is in the other kangaroo hash map, I can easily retrieve the discrete log.

My implementation works if $w$ is very close to $2h$. Otherwise it take a lot of time and memory.

What I think I might have done wrong:

- The distinguisher: I was not able to define a good distinguisher. I am storing all my values of $y_i$ and $x_i$
- The value of $k$ and how I split $G$. I defined the exponents as $e_i = 2^i$ (affecting my definition of $f$). Was that bad?

Any help will be much appreciated. I can even give the code if you are interested but it is really a long code...

Comment: It's not clear what $G$ and $C$ are, but presumably a mod $p$ multiplicative group? In any event, this doesn't look to be set-up correctly. $x_0=w/2$ is a value of unknown logarithm (you've not made it clear how it can be treated as a member of $G$) and should not allow recovery of anything.

Comment: I corrected a typo with $C$... Indeed we are working in a multiplicative group mod p aka all the multiplication and addition are done modulo a prime number p. The kangaroo algorithm assumes we know a $w$ that bounds $a$. I am not sure about the algorithm caring if $w/2$ is a member of $G$ or not ... @DanielS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things look broadly correct, though I really think that $x_0$ should be $g^{w/2}$ rather than $\mathtt{int}(w/2)$.

Note that if we write $a=w/2+\delta$ for some $-w/2\le \delta\le w/2$ then with $s$ steps we can at most be testing for $\delta$ of size $O(s\sqrt w)$ and so we expect the method to perform better for small $\delta$, though this means $w$ is close to $2a$ rather than $2h$ (being close to $2h$ should not be having any effect).

In terms of time I hope that you are precomputing $m(i):=g^{2^i}$ for $0\le i\le k-1$ using the recurrence $m(i+1)=g\cdot m(i)\mod p$, storing the result and then computing $f(x)$ as $f(x)=x\cdot m(x\mod k)\mod p$.

In terms of memory, only storing distinguished points might involve only saving $y_i$ and $x_j$ where the trailing bits are all 1s (e.g. the last 5 bits are all 1), though the number of steps will increase marginally.

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed it is my mistake another typo: $x_0$ is $g^{w/2}$ in my program ... I did not think about this optimization with precomputing $m$. I will surely try it out !!! I understand your idea of trailing bits but I can't see why it does mathematically work ... I mean by using this distinguisher isn't there a possibility of filtering out a possible kangaroo collision ?

Comment: Note that once there is a collision such as $y_i=x_j$ then all future increments will also be collisions i.e. $y_{i+1}=x_{j+1}$, $y_{i+2}=x_{j+2}$ etc. After a few increments you should hit a filtered point (e.g. after 32 or so increments if we look for the last 5 bits to be all 1s.

Comment: Your answer made my implementation much better. In my tests, when $a \simeq 2^{54.1}$ I choose $w = 2^{55}$. My program then breaks the log really fast.  However, when $a \simeq 2^{57,781}$ I choose $w = 2^{58}$. My program is then taking a lot of time to break the discrete log to get $a$. Is this normal or I am missing something again ?

Comment: When I say takes a lot of time I mean I made each kangaroos walk $1 000 000 000$ times and still nothing. Plus my algorithm doesn't have a stopping point: it either find the discrete log or run forever ...

Comment: 1,000,000,000 does not sound unreasonable; [Pollard](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s001450010010.pdf) estimates an average $3w^{1/2}$ steps when near the end of the interval which would be over 1,600,000,000 steps when $w=2^{58}$.